# SwiftUI: Clear Modal state or Reinitialize

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI modal that I would like to either clear the state of or reinitialize. Reinitalizing would be preferred considering the fact that this modal can open other modals that may have some state.

Here is a simple example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct OtherView: View {
    @State var otherViewState: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField($otherViewState, placeholder: Text("Demo Text Input"))
    }
}

struct Demo: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var modal: Modal {
        Modal(OtherView(), onDismiss: { self.showModal = false })
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showModal = true }) {
            Text("Toggle Modal")
        }
        .presentation(self.showModal ? self.modal : nil)
    }
}
```

Regardless of how OtherView is dismissed, I would like to reopen it with its text state cleared, with the requirement that OtherView could open modals itself. Adding a `clear` method on the OtherView struct itself is always an option, but I don't find it to be a maintainable one.

Below is a video of the simplified problem:
[image: Demo]

Comment: I feel that it's very rare that a modal view will actually *own* data. Think of a login screen - the modal only is binded to the actual owner of "user". Could you maybe rethink your model? Or maybe give more detail on why `otherViewState` is the "source of truth"?

Comment: Interesting. I find its reusability takes a big hit if that's the case. For example, in the iOS Reminders App, if I want to create a reminder from anywhere, would all views need to separately maintain this "new reminder" state (title, remind me on a day, priority, etc)? https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios12-iphone-x-reminders-item-info-remind-me-on-a-day.jpg

Comment: Paradigm shift? I honestly don't know. But you linked an iOS12 example. Do you think it conforms to "owner of truth" as is? We're all working on learning this (only) iOS 13 stuff called SwiftUI and Combine. For me, one (but not the only) thing is that "a view is simply a `View`". (Regards to `Combine` think in terms of memory usage and "single source or truth" to simplify it.) To me, a modal shouldn't probably (maybe?) be the owner of anything except... well, in my example, *clearing* it's content at most. Let the use decide to push changes back to the app, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update September 11th:** This appears to be fixed in iOS 13 GM.

I've been struggling with the same thing and I would like to think that this is a bug that will be resolve by September, I've already filed it on Feedback Assistant, make sure to do the same!

For now though you can just create a new UIHostingController that wraps the SwiftUI View that you want to show modally. I know it looks really hacky but at least it works:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct OtherView: View {
    @State var otherViewState: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField($otherViewState, placeholder: Text("Demo Text Input"))
    }
}

struct Demo: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Toggle Modal") {
            self.showModal()
        }
    }

    func showModal() {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
        window?.rootViewController?.present(UIHostingController(rootView: OtherView()), animated: true)
    }
}
```

You might want to improve how you get the window, specially if you support multiple windows but I think you get the idea.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was looking for. Less than ideal, but I'm sure it'll be worked out by September.

Comment: I'll mark it as the accepted answer for now considering there isn't really a viable alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I know it's not ideal but at least we can keep working. I'll keep this updated when we find a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinitialize your Modal in .onAppear().  This example works on Beta 3.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ModalView : View {

    @Environment(\.isPresented) var isPresented: Binding<Bool>?

    @State var textName: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            Form {
                Section() {
                     TextField("Name", text: self.$textName)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.grouped)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Add Name"), displayMode: .large)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action:{ self.dismiss() })
                { Text("Cancel") },
                                    trailing: Button(action:{ self.dismiss() })
                                    { Text("Save") } )
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    self.textName = ""
                })
        }
    }

    func dismiss() {
        self.isPresented?.value = false
    }

}

struct DetailView : View {

    var body: some View {

        PresentationLink(destination: ModalView())
        { Text("Present") }
    }

}

struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView())
            { Text("Navigate") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Sort of what I meant by "Adding a clear method on the OtherView struct itself is always an option" but this is a little cleaner. This works well for small state, but if I have 10-15 properties of state on a complex-ish form, it becomes a bit cumbersome

Comment: I'm not sure why it is cumbersome. You can either do assignments for the @State vars or call your struct's "clear" method. The point is that you do it from the form's .onAppear().

If this solves your problem, please upvote and accept.  Thanks.