# SwiftUI modal state not resetting with ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui

I'm working with an `ObservedObject` and editing it with a modal. All the editing and updating of the `ObservedObject` works fine, but when I edit again with the modal, it is **not** updated to the most recent state. Instead, it keeps the last state, and only until I do something that resets the state inside the modal (i.e. type in the text box), does it update.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56881222/swiftui-clear-modal-state-or-reinitialize?rq=1), but I'm using `ObservableObject`. And that question says the issue has been fixed with iOS13 GM, but I'm using Xcode 11.0 (11A420a) and iOS13 and I'm not seeing any fix.

Here is a screen recording of the problem:
[image]

All code below has been simplified to show the problem:

I have a `Batch` class which is an `ObservedObject`. I'm updating or removing the `flag` property with the modal:

```
class Batch: Identifiable, Codable, ObservableObject {
    let id: String
    private(set) var flag: String?

    init(id: String, flag: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.flag = flag
    }

    func updateFlag(flag: String?) {
        guard let flag = flag else { return }
        self.flag = flag
    }

    func removeFlag() {
        self.flag = nil
    }
}
```

The main view:

```
struct BatchView: View {
    @ObservedObject var batch: Batch
    @State private var showingModal = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                self.showingModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text(batch.flag ?? "No flag")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(batch.id), displayMode: .inline)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingModal) {
            FlagEditView(batch: self.batch)
        }
    }
}
```

The modal `FlagEditView`:

```
struct FlagEditView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @ObservedObject var batch: Batch
    @State private var flagText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("placeholder", text: $flagText)

                Button(action: {
                    self.batch.removeFlag()
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Clear flag")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Edit Flag", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.batch.updateFlag(flag: self.flagText)
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Save")
                }
            )
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I also noticed that `.onAppear` only gets called once the first time the modal is displayed, then never afterwards.